# Appium not able to scroll on iOS 8.4

Tags: java, testing, automation, appium

Im trying to scroll successfully on Appium using the following code:

```
// java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

However, am getting a javascript error when trying to scroll beyond the bottom of the UITableView due to a known appium issue:
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4836

This issue alongside the fact appium's isDisplayed() method always returns true (whether or not the cell is visible on the screen) and appium is unable to click on a non-visible cell, means that appium is unable to scroll and select objects.

Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the moment it looks like there might not be a way round this.  Darshan mentioned above the this scrolling issue still exists in iOS 8.4 and from surfing the internet it seems others have the same view

Answer (score 0):

Use flick as a possible temporary solution. We're able to flick as swipe and scroll on the screen, as well as elements.We can't actually flick on a UIAScrollView, but we can on UIACollectionView.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

To resolve issue with isDisplayed() always true you can try

```
 if(!driver.findElements(By.name(using)).isEmpty()) {
...
}
```

Replace 'using' by your locator , also I think this scrolling issue must have to resolved by Appium mobile:scroll, and your code looks fine, also you can try to use Vertical swipe instead of Scroll.

Comment: Darshan, this is using 'mobile: scroll' is that correct?  Seems very similar to my original code in the question?

Comment: I think they resolved this scrolling issue from 8.3 but it still exist in 8.4, we need to find some alternative..

Comment: Hi Darshan.  Thanks for the updated answer - will give that a go. What is the code needed for vertical swipe (rather than mobile:scroll)?